# Restricting text length dependent on an entry in another cell

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to create a data validation formula in excel to restrict the number of characters in a cell depending on what is entered in the adjacent cell.

For instance: if Cell A1 has OCEAN entered, then character count in A2 should equal 11 characters.
If A1 has Rail entered, then character count in A2 can be between 10 and 11, and
If A1 has Trailer entered, then character count in A2 can be any amount.

I have tried using this formula under the text length option in data validation  =IF(ISERROR(FIND("OCEAN",A1)),255,11) just to get it to work with the OCEAN option. It works to limit the character count, but it does regardless of what is entered in A1, not specific to the word OCEAN.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Please help if so!

[FORMULA I TRIED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOiNO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should do two changes:

1. Change the Data from "Minimum" to "Between"
2. For Minimum following is the formula:

   =IF(ISERROR(FIND("OCEAN",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Trailer",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Rail",A1)),**0,10),0)**,11)
3. For Maximum, following is the formula

   =IF(ISERROR(FIND("OCEAN",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Trailer",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Rail",A1)),**255,11),255**),11)

[image]

This is the result

```
A1          Minimum Length   Max Length
======================================== 
OCEAN       11               11
Trailer     0                255
Rail        10               11
```

Also bear in mind that the FIND function is case sensitive, This means if the A1 contains "Ocean" instead of "OCEAN", it won't gone through and your restriction won't be applied. In order to avoid such problem, you may consider to use to UPPER function to convert A1 to upper case before doing the check.

Hope this helps!